# Async for each loop exceeds maximum number of connections

Tags: javascript, mysql, asynchronous, heroku

Why is my connection not releasing in this for each loop? Instead it exceeds the maximum number of connections to my database and crashes my app. Clearly `findOneByPhone` releases the connection, but not when coupled with `Async.each` - what am I doing wrong here?

This function is being run in an async for each loop.

```
this.findOneByPhone = function(phone, req, res, callback) {
        connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
            con.query('select * from users where phone = ?', [phone], function(err, result) {
                con.release()
                if (err) {
                    callback(err)
                } else {
                    callback(null, JSON.stringify(result[0], null, 4))
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Here's the loop.

```
var friendsAlreadySignedUp = []

        Async.each(friends, function(friend, callback) {
            var formattedNumber = Phone.format(Phone.parse(friend.phoneNumbers[0].number, {country: { default: 'US' }}), 'International_plaintext')
            User.findOneByPhone(formattedNumber, null, null, function(err, foundUser) {
                // If user exists in DB, add corresponding object to friendsAlreadySignedUp
                if (foundUser) {
                    var foundUserJSON = JSON.parse(foundUser)
                    foundUserJSON.originalNumber = friend.phoneNumbers[0].number
                    friendsAlreadySignedUp.push(foundUserJSON)
                    callback()
                } else {
                    callback()
                }
            })
        }, function() {
            res.json({status: 0, message: 'findFriends succeeded.', result: friendsAlreadySignedUp})
        })
```

And it causes this.

```
Error: ER_USER_LIMIT_REACHED: User 'b85497d5b39b53' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 15)
```

Comment: Since there's no explanation what `acquire` does this is anyone's guess.

Comment: Without looking into it in depth: are you able to have one connection and make multiple queries with that single connection? Databases (especially sql) typically like to only have 1 'user' connected at a time to avoid collisions, and it sounds like you're hitting the max number of 'connected users' that your sql server allows